# Generate Socket in C under Linux and wireshark detect error in frame

Tags: c, linux, sockets, wireshark

I create Socket in C under Linux using the "traditional way":

```
sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Right after, we connect it (successfully) and the frame is sent using:

```
send(sock, buffer, bufferSize, 0);
```

Unfortunately, when frame is send to automaton, it doesn't "receive" it (we don't know why).
But if it sends to "classical" server it's ok.

So, when I have checked the frame with wireshark, it raised a problem:

```
Malformed Packet
```

[image]

As you can see, frame #6 is malformed.
It looks like there is a problem in TCP header but what and how solve it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's will be easier to help you if we can see the entire code snippet.

Comment: Please write an MCVE, which reproduces the problem for you (and nothing else, so I suppose it will be around... 20 lines of code).

Comment: And please also add a better explanation of how your "automation" server is different from the "classical" server.

Comment: Wireshark does not think that the packet is a TCP packet, which evaluation would be based on the contents of its IP header.  The only explanations that occur to me at the moment are that either something is rewriting the packet (firewall / netfilter), or the program is doing something much stranger than so far has been divulged, or the machine is broken.  In any case, that explains why the payload is not received by the peer socket.

Comment: Port 3632 is the standard port for distcc. I guess your system happens to use this port which makes Wireshark try to interpret it as a DISTCC protocol. It doesn't show an error in the TCP data but in the DISTCC data. Check if you see the expected data in your packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, frame #6 is malformed. It looks like there is a problem in TCP header but what and how solve it?

Wireshark tries to interpret the packet as communication from [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc), probably because it is using the port for distcc (3632). It does not complain about anything in the TCP header but it complains that it fails to interpret the payload of the packet as distcc application layer protocol.

While nothing about your application is known it is likely not using the distcc protocol but it is just using the port 3632. Insofar the information from wireshark is wrong since you've never intended to use the distcc protocol. To "fix" the problem in wireshark move to another port or disabling interpretation of your port in wireshark as distcc.

Note that this only fixes the wrong display of the packet as malformed (since its not). It has nothing to do with fixing the communication you've actually intended and there are no information in your question which would help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all of your comments (and requests). 
The problem came from the port as mentioned buy Steffen Ullrich.

I have switched server and client from 3632 to 3633 port and wireshark analyse frame as "classical" TCP protocol and every if is ok.